# Ionic Google Analytics Track Category

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, ionic3, google-analytics-campaign-builder

I can track my web campaigns without problem like:

```
ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'WebApp');
ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'WebApp');
```

But in Ionic when I integrate like below, I can see as active user but I could not see campaign name.

```
    this.ga.startTrackerWithId(this.singleton.googleAnalyticsTrackId)
   .then(() => {
     console.log('Google analytics is ready now');
        this.ga.trackView('mobile');
        this.ga.setVar('campaignMedium','mobile').then(d=>console.log(d));
        this.ga.setVar('campaignSource','mobile').then(d=>console.log(d));
   })
   .catch(e => console.log('Error starting GoogleAnalytics', e));
```

Is there any suggestion or solution?